# row color jsf primeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using `datatable` and each `row` in table should have different color according to a value of one of the property of row `StatutTicket` 
this my code view:

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTickets" var="ticket"
        rowStyleClass="#{ticket.statutTicket.libelleStatutTicket == 'En attente' ? 'background-color:red': 'background-color:red'}"
        value="#{ticketBean.tickets}">
        <p:column headerText="N Ticket" sortBy="#{ticket.idTicket}"
            filterBy="#{ticket.idTicket}">
            <h:outputText value="#{ticket.idTicket}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Statut Ticket">
            <h:outputText value="#{ticket.statutTicket.libelleStatutTicket}" />
        </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

But the color of the column  still not change and the error not appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `rowStyleClass` attribute accept `css` class-type instead of direct using as

```
rowStyleClass="#{ticket.statutTicket.libelleStatutTicket eq 'En attente' ? 'background-color:red': 'background-color:red'}"
```

Use something like this.

```
rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
rowStyleClass="#{(rowIndex mod 2) eq 0 ? 'redClass': 'blueClass'}"
```

And add this class in your `css` file as so that you will have two different color for two consecutive rows.

```
.redClass {
    background-color:red;
}
.blueClass {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Check what it returns `#{ticket.statutTicket.libelleStatutTicket eq 'En attente'}` ?? if this returns boolean then this will definitely work.

Comment: Qadir Hussain how can I do for checking

Answer (score 0):

Try comparison of Strings using `eq` instead of `==`.
Or consider using the backing bean to determine the `styleClass`, e.g.:

```
rowStyleClass="#{ticketBean.styleClass(ticket)}"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is work for me.

```
    .rowWarnning {
        background-color: #FF9933 !important;
        background-image: none !important;
        color: #000000 !important;
    }

    <p:dataTable id="dataTickets" var="ticket"
        rowStyleClass="#{ticket.statutTicket.libelleStatutTicket == 'En attente' ? 'rowWarnning': null}"
        value="#{ticketBean.tickets}">
```